# spree install issue - using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am trying to install the spree gem using the following instructions
http://spreecommerce.com/resources/quick-start

The install worked fine, but trying to create an application doesn't resolve

```
bash: spree: command not found
```

PATH is 
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin:/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin
bash-3.2$

Should I add something from the below output to my PATH?

```
bash-3.2$ find $HOME -name spree
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/doc/spree-0.30.0/rdoc/lib/generators/spree
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/doc/spree_auth-0.30.0/rdoc/lib/spree
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/doc/spree_core-0.30.0/rdoc/lib/spree
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/spree-0.30.0/lib/generators/spree
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/spree_auth-0.30.0/app/controllers/spree
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/spree_auth-0.30.0/lib/spree
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/spree_core-0.30.0/app/controllers/spree
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/spree_core-0.30.0/app/helpers/spree
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/spree_core-0.30.0/lib/spree
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/spree_core-0.30.0/public/images/spree
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Same problem here, any solutions?

Comment: Actually, newer versions of spree don't have a command line tool installed. Instead it's a rails engine. See "4 Creating a New Spree Project" here: http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/getting_started.html

Comment: That tutorial for install Spree says to use sudo. [Do NOT use sudo when installing a gem if your Ruby is under RVM's control](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/) unless you KNOW what you are doing and why you would want to do that. RVM uses a sandbox and `sudo` will do a jailbreak and put the gem in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3):

What Chris said: You can create a rails 3.0 app and add the spree gem to the app, as documented in http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/getting_started.html#creatinga-new-spree-project.

1. Create you project with e.g., `rails new spreetest`
2. Add `gem 'spree'` to the Gemfile
3. Perform `bundle install` to install missing gems
4. Initialize the spree site with `rails g spree:site` and `rake spree:install`
5. Optionally, install sample data `rake spree_sample:install`
6. Populate the database with `rake db:bootstrap`
7. Run the server with `rails server`

Answer (score -1):

From what I read on Spree homepage, they recommend you to perform the Gem installation using `sudo`. However, [RVM says you should not use sudo](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/). Try installing the Gem again, this time without `sudo`.

Comment: The whole purpose of RVM is to avoid installation of gems on system level as root using sudo.

Comment: @Munhitsu, That's what my answer says, to NOT use sudo.